# how to pass e.target value when i call the same function another place in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Here is the validation function I created:

```
checkValidation: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var data = $(e.target).val();
    var color = (data === '') ? '#F00' : '#000';

    $(e.target).css({ 'border': '1px solid ' + color });
}
```

This validation function is called whenever the focusout event is triggered:

```
events: {
    'click #commentSubmit':'commentSubmitFun',
    'focusout #commUserName':'checkValidation',
    'focusout #commUserMsg':'checkValidation'
}
```

Now I want to call the same `checkValidation` function inside the `commentSubmitFun` like this:

```
if (userName !== '' && userComment !== '' {...}  else { this.checkValidation(); }
```

However, how do I pass `e.target` into the `checkValidation` function?

Answer (score 1):

When your `commentSubmitFun` is called on click, it will be passed the `event` as well. If you plan to call `checkValidation` within `commentSubmitFun`, you can pass the `event` object as an argument into your `checkValidation` call.

To be honest though, I would suggest refactoring your `checkValidation` function to take a String `data` as the parameter. This way, whenever you call `checkValidation`, you'll have to pass in the data that you're checking explicitly.

Comment: thanks wmock for your reply i tried but may be syntax error .. could you please suggest me the syntax..

Comment: You have to be more explicit with what you tried - it's very difficult to help answer your questions without you providing what you tried and what syntax error you got.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @wmock's answer. But I think it'd be better to add a new answer with code.

Since you already have the `checkValidation` function expecting an `Event` object `e` as argument, you just pass `e` to it to make it work. So when you need to invoke `checkValidation` in `commentSubmitFun()`, just  `checkValidation(e)` and it should work.

```
commentSubmitFun: function(e) {
    // e is the click event occured on #commentSubmit element
    if (youNeedCheck) {
        checkValidatoin(e)
    }
}
```

---

But I don't think it is a good idea to use checkValidation as an event listener, which would lead to a restriction that you **must** pass an `Event` object as the only arguments to invoke the function. Actually, an event listener is designed to be triggered only when an event occurs, it is bound to the event and should not be invoked elsewhere.

You'd better take an `element` as a parameter like this

```
checkValidation: function (el) {
    var data = $(el).val();
    var color = (data === '') ? '#F00' : '#000';

    $(el).css({ 'border': '1px solid ' + color });
}
```

Then you just invoke this `checkValidation` function whenever you need to validate something. Remember to refactor your code in events object.

```
events: {
    // ...
    'focusout #commUserName':'checkUserName'
}

checkUserName: function(e) {
    checkValidation(e.target);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off there are three separate concerns at play here

- Checking validity of some data
- Handling validation error
- Invoking validation logic

In the simplest case, you get away with four functions,

```
function checkElementValidity($el) { 
    // some logic. return true or 
    // object describing an error. 
    // if valid, return false. 
}

function displayValidationError($el, err) {
    // logic to display it.
}

function handleChange(evt) {
   // stop progagation.
   var $el = $(evt.target);
   var result = checkElementValidity($el);
   // depending on result
   displayValidationError($el);  
}

function validateAllElements(){
   var elems = [this.$el.find("#id-1"), this.$el.find("#id-2") ...];
   var isValid = true;
   elems.map(function ($el) {return {$el: $el, res: checkElementValidity($el);})
        .filter(function (data) {return data.res;})
        .forEach(function (data) { isValid = false;
             displayValidationError(data.$el, data.res)});
   return isValid;
}
```

Elsewhere,

```
events: {
    'click #commentSubmit':'commentSubmitFun',
    'focusout #commUserName':'handleChange',
    'focusout #commUserMsg':'handleChange'
}

function commentSubmitForm(evt){
   // your logic
   var isValid = validateAllElements();
}
```

I don't use Backbone, so the code might not work as is. It does however illustrate the approach you may take. The exact implementation is upto you, you could collapse all 4 functions into one if you want. The important part is realizing there are separate concerns at play.